# Browser gives 200 return while requests.get gives 403

Tags: python, request, cloudflare

I don't quiet understand what I am missing.  If I open a new browser, cleared of all cookies, cache, everything, and go to this an api endpoint for a specific site ("api.site.com/data?key=my_key"), I get a proper 200 response with data returned.  I go to dev tools in my browser, copy every header sent with that request and include it in my request:

```
headers =  {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "api.site.com",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1"
    }
r = requests.get("api.site.com/data?key=my_key", headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

Return status code is 403 though and I get a cloudflare 1020 error.  What else am I missing that allows cloudflare to distinguish between these two requests?  The headers are identical, it's a simple get request, no cookies are being sent either.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I am giving an agent.

Comment: I think that website has a robot protection that uses some sort of fingerprinting. Check if you can access the website with a Firefox that has all sorts of fingerprinting disabled. If you have something JS based you might actually need a headless browser.

Comment: @asdasd31 Is your Python script running on the same machine (local), or on a different machine?