# Python request returning 403

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use `requests` to make an api call that this page is making https://www.betonline.ag/sportsbook/martial-arts/mma.

```
requests.post(
    url='https://api.betonline.ag/offering/api/offering/sports/offering-by-league',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'}
    json={"Sport":"martial-arts","League":"mma","ScheduleText":None,"Period":0}
)
```

[image: Request through Chrome]

I have also tried including all the headers I see in the image but am still unable to get a 200 and get the response.

What am I missing?

Comment: The response status shows 200.  So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: That is the response status in chrome network tab but when I try in python it does not work @ewong

Comment: So, it is 200 in a normal browser, but 403 in your program? Maybe some kind of protection from bots.

Comment: Correct 200 in normal browser, 403 in my python code @qrsngky

Comment: Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816008/browser-gives-200-return-while-requests-get-gives-403

Comment: Authentication cookie?

Comment: I don't see one getting passed in chrome @zigarn

Comment: May also be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572674/python-3-web-scraping-error-403
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/problem-http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping

Comment: 403 related to the Authorization problem,  you don’t have permission to access this resource is an HTTP status code that occurs when the web server understands the request but can’t provide additional access.